# can I change text to input box with click the text in bootstrap or thymeleaf?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

here is my sample code.

```
<table id="sampleTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>th1</th>
            <th>th2</th>
            <th>th3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="cursor:pointer"> <!-- I want to click this row -->
            <td> text1</td> <!-- when the row is clicked, I want to change this text "text1" to "<input>" tag. -->
            <td> text2</td>
            <td> text3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

there aren't any thymeleaf tag, but I can use them whem I want to.

Comment: add what you have tried so far

Comment: I prefer to use only bootstrap. however if I can't, I also possible to use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/8h00oc9d/1/

```js
$('table tbody tr').click(function(){
 $($(this).children()[0]).html('<input type="text" />')
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="sampleTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>th1</th>
            <th>th2</th>
            <th>th3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="cursor:pointer"> <!-- I want to click this row -->
            <td> text1</td> <!-- when the row is clicked, I want to change this text "text1" to "<input>" tag. -->
            <td> text2</td>
            <td> text3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it works well.
and, is there any idea when I change other fields, how can I know what I clicked?
using id, index or anything

Comment: My pleasure @JacobAidenSon :)

Answer (score 0):

I this it's shoud work .

```
$("tableSelector").delegate("tr.rows", "click", function(){
    $("td").append("stuff you want to append");
});
```